# How prevent gramarly to scan text in my react.elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, browser

I'm using Grammarly as firefox extension but on the website I'm building Grammarly scan the scan inside my buttons elements. How prevent this? I have no clue about browser extension's interaction with my code.

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: If pages could disable browser extensions they'd all become pretty useless.

Comment: you can obfuscate code (html result) - e.g. make every character of that button in other element like facebook does it with ads right now

Comment: @fard thanks for your answer :), can you explicit your solution please, a little example would be great

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Yep, good point ! But ya know sometimes you want to make custom writting hence for my example is relatively boring

Comment: @Webwoman https://codesandbox.io/s/7y7351xx1j